# random walk inside a square (probability of escape before returning)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

My question comes from Exercise 9.7. of the book "Markov Chains and Mixing Times (2nd edition)" written by David A.Levin and Yuval Peres. Specifically, let $B_n$ be the subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the box of side length $2n$ centered at $0$. Let $\partial B_n$ be the set of vertices along the perimeter of the box. The problem statement asks us to show that for simple random walk on $B_n$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}_0\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < \tau^+_0\} = 0.$$ I think it is intuitively clear but have no idea on how this can be justified analytically. Since this problem is in Chapter 9, I guess the author wants us to use the theory of network reduction laws/rules developed in the context of "random walks on networks". Any hint or help are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have something, if I dindn't make any mistake.

$\mathbb{P}_0\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < \tau^+_0\} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N} } \mathbb{P}\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < \tau^+_0 |\tau^+_0 =k \} \mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 =k \} = \sum_{k \geq n }  \mathbb{P}\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < \tau^+_0 |\tau^+_0 =k \} \mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 =k \}  \leq \sum_{k \geq n }  \mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 =k \}  = \mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 \geq n \}$

Overall $\mathbb{P}_0\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < \tau^+_0\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 \geq n \}$ which mean that if a random walk touch the boundary of $B_n$ and then go back to $0$ then the first return map to $0$ take at least $n$ step.

Obviously $\mathbb{P}\{ \tau^+_0 \geq n \} \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$

Comment: For your first identity, it can't be true, by definition, if the walker starts at 0, then $\tau_0 =0$ almost surely... So the condition $\tau_0 = k$ doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Sorry I write it too quickly. Every $\tau_0$ is $\tau^+_0$ . I edited my answer.

Comment: For the second equality, why you can replace $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ by $\sum_{k\geq n}$?

Comment: If $k<n$ then $\mathbb{P}_0\{\tau_{\partial B_n} < k \} =0$

Comment: I see. A final question: is there a rigorous way to justify your last statement (even though it looks obvious). I remember that 2D simple random walk is recurrent...

Comment: Yes, one can show that $\tau_0^+$ has a first moment (because its probability is for example less than a D1 random walk) . Then you use Markov inequality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113080/discussion-between-etiennebfx-and-fei-cao).

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{E}_0(\tau^+_0) = \infty$, meaning that the mean expected return time is infinite! So $\tau^+_0$ does not possess a finite first moment (you can check this fact in any standard probability/stochastic process textbook)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't check this affirmation, my bad. Otherwise as $\sum_{ k \in \mathbb{N}^{*} } \mathbb{P}\{ \tau_0^{+} = k \} =1$, $\mathbb{P} \{ \tau_0^+ \geq n \}$ is the tail of a convergent serie, which go to zero. I wanted to give a more quantitatif result.

Comment: This makes more sense then. Thanks! Btw, I also have another question with bounty (even though it expired), if you are interested you can try it.